# Want to display few words before and end of search keyword

Tags: php, mysql

For example I have a string in database table

> "This is a test and I want to test everything on my website using
>   testing tool. I need help of my people to search the new things on
>   portal but I can not find any source of help"

This data is in my mysql table

No when I search a word or string in this content then I want to display first 20 and next 20 words with Search string

For example if I search **my people**

Then I should get result as following

website using testing tool. I need help of **my people** to search the new things

Or if I search **portal** then it should give result as following

I need help of my people to search the new things on portal but I can not find any source of help

I tried using mysql like query but it show full content.

Answer (score -1):

You can use mysql LIKE statement and then use php explode function to get the single sentence. Do a strpos checking on the exploded pieces to see whether you are taking the correct result.

```
$keyword        = "portal";
$result_str     =  "This is a test and i want to test everything on my website using testing tool. I need help of my people to search the new things on portal but i can not find any source of help";
$suggestions    =  explode(".", $result_str);
$match          = "";
foreach ($suggestions as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value,$keyword) !==false)
        $match = $value;
    continue;
}

echo $match;
```

Comment: please demonstrate how the OP would do this

Comment: #ash_8247 can you give me a small code for help how to do this? I tried but do not work for me, it will help me a lot

Comment: @FreeTutorials: Edited my answer. Please check it

Comment: This will return the full complete sentence that matches your keyword.